# How to load image to swf which is loaded into other swf? (AIR, AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an application in AIR, which is loading swf files and makes previews of them. When those swfs loads other content (eg. jpg) then i have an error, that url not found - i am convinced that is about jpg file. This problem shows only when i load swf by filereference using loadBytes(). When i load swf by  Loader using load() - problem doesn`t exist. How can i fix this issue? Sorry for my english. I attach code fragment with loading swfs.

```
    private static function loadFile(loadType:String, swfNum:Number = 0):void {
        lc = new LoaderContext();
        lc.allowCodeImport = true;
        lc.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution = true;

        currentSwfNum = swfNum;

        var fRef:FileReference = DataBase.swfsList[currentSwfNum];
        fRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileReferenceLoad);
        fRef.load();
    }

    private static function onFileReferenceLoad(e:Event):void {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ifComplete);
        loader.loadBytes(e.target.data, lc);
    }

    private static function ifComplete(e:Event):void {
        var mc:MovieClip = LoaderInfo(e.target).content as MovieClip;
        mc.addEventListener("SHOOT", SwfSingleCapture.captureSingleShoot);
    }
```

DataBase.swfList - it is an array of FileReference objects, which are selected by FileReferenceList and browse().

Comment: Loader operations need a LoaderContext even when using loadBytes.

Comment: Yes, I know. Thats why i used loader.loadBytes(e.target.data, lc); where lc is LoaderContext defined in loadFile function

Comment: Ok, now its strange. When I testing app in flash professional it works fine (I don't know why - I didn't make any changes), but when I publish it to .app version it doesn't work, like earlier...